# SEO URL based on category name without have a category id in URL

Tags: php, url-rewriting, seo

I have two table `posts` & `categories`

```
post_id | post_title  | post_content   | post_cat
--------------------------------------------------
1         Hello World  welcome to my..   1
.         ..           ..                ..
```

`categories` table

```
cat_id | cat_name | cat_parent
-----------------------------
1        News       NULL
2        Sports     1
.        ...        ..
```

Let's say current category link for news is `http://domain.com/category/1/`

MySQL statment

```
SELECT posts.post_id,
       posts.post_id,
       posts.post_title,
       posts.post_content,
       posts.post_cat,
       categories.cat_id,
       categories.cat_name,
       categories.cat_parent
FROM   posts
       INNER JOIN categories
         ON posts.post_cat = categories.cat_id  
       WHERE posts.post_cat = (int)$_GET['cat_id']
```

So we can get a result for `post_cat = 1`

According to my current database structure, how do I remove the `ID` but change it to be a nice slug? Example :-

```
Main category - http://domain.com/category/news/
Sub category  - http://domain.com/category/news/sports/
```

Let me know a clue how script will tell `News` is equal `1` on `post_cat` column?

Comment: An [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file might be able to help you.  You'll want to [rewrite the URL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: I see you are casting the parameter received in the `$_GET` array - **good game**.  You should always make sure that your are sanitizing data that could be tampered by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an [.htaccess file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) to [rewrite the URL's](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for you.

The entry in the `.htaccess` file would look something like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^category 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ parseCategoryUrl.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'll break down the lines here to help understand whats going on and what each line means :

1. Turn the RewriteEngine on.
2. This rewrite will only occur on URL's where the first word after the host name is `category` - all URL's starting with that word will be processed by the lines below.
3. The rule will **exclude** URL's that point to *actual* files `!-f`
4. The rule will **exclude** URL's that point to *actual* directories `!-d`
5. The actual rule will capture the entire request_uri and pass it to the `parseCategoryUrl.php` file with the entire request as a parameter called `q` (query) in the $_GET array. The flags at the end of the rule (L,QSA) do two things.

   - L - This is the last rule.  After processing this line the `.htaccess` file will stop performing actions on the current URL.
   - QSA - Append the query string to the rewritten URL (so that we can parse it later).

Your `parseCategoryUrl.php` file could contain something similar to the following :

```
$request = explode('/',$_GET['q'] );
array_shift($request);
```

The first line will split the request by slashes into an array - and the second line removes the word category from the beginning of the array (because we know that we are parsing a category URL).

The final `$request` array, with a URL example such as :
`http://example.domain.com/category/news/sports`
Will be this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => news
    [1] => sports
)
```

So you see here that you have now successfully split the URL into an array;  All you have to do now is query your database and and provide the user with the correct page.
Because the `parseCategoryUrl.php` page in fact has no output, you could just use an `include()` function to insert the correct page according to the URL that was provided.

---

SEO is about making your pages and their URL's more informative to search engines so that a user searching the internet will be able to receive page results that are related to their search query.  A search engine looking at the URL :
`http://domain.com/category/1/2`
will not be able to extract much information.  However if your URL contains (as your question requires),  category information, then a search engine will be able to deduct that the specific  URL is related to :

- `http://domain.com/category/news/` - news
- `http://domain.com/category/news/sports` - sports news
- `http://domain.com/category/blog/` - blog
- etc...

Comment: You are most welcome @UnknownError!  Many people are hesitant to utilize `.htaccess` files because of their mystic and black magic nature ;)  They are in fact a very powerful and useful tool *(in the right hands)*

Comment: essentially you don't **have** to remove that first element - its just redundant to have that in the array because we have already started parsing categories.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

It is not as different as generate an url with id. Use the same logic to generate the url with title. However they way I see it, there is only one thing, you need to remember.

#### The category name **has** to be unique at all cost.

Place a .htaccess to ensure the titles are properly redirected you the page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Then, instead of using `id` in the query use the `title`

```
SELECT posts.post_id,
       posts.post_id,
       posts.post_title,
       posts.post_content,
       posts.post_cat,
       categories.cat_id,
       categories.cat_name,
       categories.cat_parent
FROM   posts
       INNER JOIN categories
         ON posts.post_cat = categories.cat_id  
Where 
      categories.cat_name = 'News'
```

---

As for the subcategory also, the above query should work, since all the categories are placed in same table.

Comment: Looks like I need to create another column on `categories` table example `slug`. So if the category name is `Ask Question` slug will be `ask-question` and in the `post_cat` column will be `ask-question`?

Comment: @UnknownError, yes it will remove the extra logic needed for the application to work, and make the coding lot more easier.

Comment: @Lix, I get your point, and you did present a good solution. Now, there is no SEO rules, that `http://domain.com/category/news/` is more SEO friendly than `http://domain.com/news/`, unless the web application demands it. The only advantage from your technique is, it makes the application scalable and its good. But that is not what is asked, and that is not what I need to give. Since you already gave it.

Comment: My example was `http://domain.com/category/1/` over `http://domain.com/news/`.  So we are on the same line.  After your edit I removed my comment.  With the addition of the `.htaccess` your answer is complete :)