# ASP.NET MVC Specify Category/Path outside of URL Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, cookies, routes

I have a problem to make a decision for putting Category/Path on URL Routing. Assume I have some products in my sample Web Application those attached to some categories. For example:

```
Book1 Attached to -> Category1 | Category2 
Book2 Attached to -> Category1 | Category2 | Category3
Book3 Attached to -> Category2 | Category3
```

And defined routing map for products is:

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{languageCode}/{category}/{product}"
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ViewItem" }
```

So possible routing for Book1 are:

```
[Domain Name]/Home/ViewItem/en-US/Category1/Book1
[Domain Name]/Home/ViewItem/en-US/Category2/Book1
```

And possible routing for Book2 are:

```
[Domain Name]/Home/ViewItem/en-US/Category1/Book2
[Domain Name]/Home/ViewItem/en-US/Category2/Book2
[Domain Name]/Home/ViewItem/en-US/Category3/Book2
```

I want to save and know current category but have single unique URL for each product(For search engine tracking and sharing URLs purpose). I think about using **Session Variable** or **ViewBag** even **Cookie**, But each of them has own limitations and cons. For example using cookies may cause some troubles: ***if set expiration time too small, it may lost current path when user pausing on some pages and if set it too long, may lead user to old browsing path even user requested for home page in new opening browser because of existing cookie*** (Except that, I'v some experiences with cookies and I believe that is not working precisely all times), About **Session** and **ViewBag** I don't know if using them is the best idea, So can anyone share tested solution or good idea? I will appreciate that.

Comment: I amazed by down voting without any comments, description or reason for that. I set my 50 valuable point as bounty because your answer is so vital for me. If you understand my question and knowing about solution, so please answer, Otherwise leave it. If you think that is stupid question and decide to voting down, at least write a comment and say what is your reason. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the page mywebsite.com/product1 (the canonical version of the URL). Including all the versions of the URL won't help. Likely, it will just confuse Google and may lead to Google ignoring certain URLs

Even if you put in the canonical version and have the rel canonical tag on your pages, Google may still choose to treat another version of the URL as canonical.

Ideally, then, I'd solve the real problem here and just have one version of the product URL on your site (have the versions with the category in the URL redirect to the version of the URL with no category in the URL). That way you don't even have to worry about all the issues duplicate content may cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But the most important matter is how to store and track selected category? After redirecting URL to Non-Category version I'll lose it, Am I wrong?

Comment: As you are the only responder to this question, I'll give you the bounty if nothing else better answer that before expiring, But didn't mark as the answer because of I'm not convinced with this answer yet.

Comment: I think @Mikaal deserve to have the bounty, But I appreciate you for your heeds, I will point your answer +1, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this isn’t a routing problem, rather an architectural issue. I think that the “language code” and “category” should be an attribute of the Book object, rather than being a part of the route.

You would then have URLs like:

{domain}/{controller}/book/id

And for “category” specific or “language code” specific views, you could have URLs like:

{domain}/{controller}/search?languageCode=enUS&category=1

This would still be perfectly RESTful and in my opinion, much simpler as well.

Comment: I Don't want to have URL in form of "?param=value&..." you can look at great websites and you will see language codes is part of URL like "/en/..." because of some content may exist in one language and didn't exist in another, So having language code in URL is logical, But about categories you may navigate to special product from different categories, The product is unique but category! I need to know category without having in URL.

Comment: If you want to avoid having anything in the URL you can do a POST request instead of GET, that way they wouldn’t show up in the URL.

Comment: If you want to keep track of the category without having to store it in the URL, you can:
1) Pass it along as a request parameter (in a POST or GET request, depending on whether or not you want it showing up in the URL).
2) Pass it along using the ViewBag. If you want to persist that for a longer period, you can add it to the session, but you’ll also have to make sure you update that whenever a category is switched. And reading from you question above, I would suggest you to store just the “categoryName/categoryId” in the “Session” / “ViewBag” / “Request Parameter” instead of a “Path”.

Comment: Please read the question again, I know about this ways, But I don't know which way is most logical and "Search Engine Friendly"! I described in question what issues and concerns exist on using any of these.

Comment: Based on my knowledge “How you persist ‘category’ at your server?” is going to have no implications on SEO / Search Friendliness of your webpages, because search engines are agnostic of your server internals. And from a technical standpoint, which approaches to follow depends entirely on you, if you don’t need to persist ‘category’ for a longer period than “ViewBag” might be a good, simple solution. Otherwise, session would be fine too.

Comment: However, what is going to have a slight impact on SEO is the URL itself that you end up creating because eventually the webpage(s) these URLs represent will end up being indexed somewhere against some search query.

Comment: A good rule of thumb as per REST guidelines would be to have one unique URI for each resource. If you have multiple URIs representing the same resource, than you might probably end up reducing SEO as rather then have a singe heavily visited page, you’d have two slightly less visited pages. And I think former is the better. Beyond that I do not know of how it might have an impact on SEO.

Comment: Think you shared URL for a special product in for example Facebook and you have a category in that URL, After while, you delete this category but the product, Now that URL won't work because of the category not exist, This is a simple example to understand my sight.

Comment: Ahhh I see. That’s quite an interesting perspective. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546635/seo-url-based-on-category-name-without-have-a-category-id-in-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
might shed some more light on it.

Comment: "rather then have a singe heavily visited page, you’d have two slightly less visited pages"  <--  I don't want this, A target product is unique so URL to that must be unique too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170809/discussion-between-qmaster-and-mikaal-anwar).

Comment: Sure thing ... Do give this a read https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls
Point # 4 is very relevant to your query.

Comment: I moved this discussion to chat.

Comment: Chat room is here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170809/discussion-between-qmaster-and-mikaal-anwar

Comment: Although You did not recommend an exact solution I see you spend the time to answer the question and paid attention to this matter, I'll be glad to hear from you about correct solution to this issue, but for now, I think you deserved to have the bounty Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I hope our discussion was helpful in at least getting closer to if not arriving at an exact solution. I will let you know if I come with a more precise answer.

Comment: Certainly, we will close to the solution after discussion, Appreciate that, You're welcome :)